# Dimension of kernel of operator on polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, polynomials

Question 1. Take $P = \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n] = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}V_i$, while $V_i$ are the $i$th component (vector space) of the graded ring $P$ with respect to the degree.

Define the following operator for fixed $r,i$:
$f_{r}: V_i\rightarrow V_{\max{(i-r,0)}}$ such that 
$f_{r}(p) = (\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial^r x_i})p$

Define kernel of $f_r$ on $V_i$ as $\ker_{r,i} =\{f_r(p)=0, p\in V_i\}$.

Then what is $\dim(\ker_{r,i})$ and $\dim(\cap_{0<r} \ker_{r,i})$, or is there any explicit expression of above dimension with respect to $r,i$? The dimensions are considered to be the dimension of vector space over $\mathbb{R}$.

Question 2. Take $P = \mathbb{R}[x_1,\dots, x_n,y_1,\dots, y_n] = \bigoplus_{i=0}^{\infty}V_i$, while $V_i$ are the $i $th component (vector space) of graded ring with respect to the degree.

Define the following operator for fixed $r,s,i$:
$ f_{r,s}: V_i\rightarrow V_{\max{(i-r-s,0)}}$ such that 
$f_{r,s}(p) = (\sum_{i=1}^n\frac{\partial}{\partial^r x_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial^s y_i})p$

Define kernel of $f_{r,s}$ on $V_i$ as $\ker_{r,s,i} =\{f_{r,s}(p)=0, p\in V_i\}$.

Then what is the number of $\dim(\ker_{r,s,i})$ and $\dim(\cap_{0<r+s}\ker_{r,s,i})$, or is ther is an explicit expression of above dimensions with respect to $r,s,i$.

Is there any reference for related topics? I think this kind of questions might have been studied. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Here's a couple things: 1) you've used $i$ twice for different things in the definition of your operators. 2) You can write down monomial bases of each of these spaces, write down the matrix, and compute small examples to find patterns. It should be relatively doable. 3) Hint: when writing down the matrix, if you choose a basis of monomials on the source/target spaces, there cannot be any cancellations when computing on a basis element as the input (examine the degrees) and you can only get something nonzero if there's a variable of at least degree $r$.